# SimpleXMLIterator performance PHP

Tags: php, performance, simplexml

I have the following three functions that are interacting with the Amazon API. When I use the parse_orders_result function, it appears to take approximately 30 seconds to complete. I discovered this by running this get_orders function with the parse_orders_result commented out, and it completes each iteration of the do while loop in 3 seconds. However, when I run the parsing stuff, it takes the 30 seconds I mentioned below. How can I improve the performance of this operation?

GET_ORDERS function:

```
public function get_orders($date)
        {
        $this->throttle = amazon_throttle::list_orders_throttle();
        $this->endpoint = "mws.amazonservices.com";
        $this->url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/$date";
        $this->action = "ListOrders";
        $this->version = '2011-01-01';
        $this->api = "/Orders/$date\n"; 
        $this->options = array( 
                                'Action' => 'ListOrders',
                                'OrderStatus.Status.1'=>'Unshipped',
                                'OrderStatus.Status.2'=>'PartiallyShipped', 
                                'OrderStatus.Status.3'=>'Shipped',
                                'OrderStatus.Status.4'=>'Canceled',//Get all unshipped, partially shipped, shipped, and canceled orders. This will update these types of orders if their status changes on Amazon
                                'LastUpdatedAfter'=> date("c", strtotime('-1 Month')) //FIXME update this to reflect our download interval later
                               );
        $this->create_signature();
        try 
            {       
            $results = $this->send_request(); //commented out for testing
            }
        catch (Exception $e)
            {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return false;
            } 

        //$results = sql::value("SELECT api_response from dhs.dbo.api_response where id = 444");
        $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($results); //make the iterator here so we can check for a nexttoken
        $orders = $this->parse_orders_result($xml->ListOrdersResult->Orders);
        if ($xml->ListOrdersResult->NextToken)
            {
            $next_token = (string)$xml->ListOrdersResult->NextToken;
            do 
                {
                $results = $this->get_orders_next_token($next_token);
                $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator($results);
                $returned = $this->parse_orders_result($xml->ListOrdersByNextTokenResult->Orders);
                $orders = array_merge($orders, $returned);
                if ($xml->ListOrdersByNextTokenResult->NextToken)
                    $next_token = (string) $xml->ListOrdersByNextTokenResult->NextToken;
                else
                    $next_token = null;
                }
            while($next_token);
            }
        //this stored procedure creates patient_ids for each order (if the patient doesn't already exist) and updates the orders table with with their patient_id
        sql::query('EXEC dhs.dbo.sp_create_patients');
        return $orders;
        }
```

PARSE_ORDERS_RESULT function:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('amz', 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01');
            $orders = array();

            foreach ($xml->Order as $order)
            {
                $last = null;
                $name = explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^A-z ]/', '', (string) $order->BuyerName)); //remove all special characters
                if (!isset($name[1]) || !$name[1])
                {
                    $attn_last = explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^A-z ]/', '',$order->ShippingAddress->Name)); //remove all special characters
                    $pos = count($attn_last) - 1;
                    $last = $attn_last[$pos];
                }
                $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', (string) $order->ShippingAddress->Phone); //remove everything that is not an int
                $phone = "(" . substr($phone, 0,3) . ")" . substr($phone,3, 3) . "-" . substr($phone, 6); //format phone number

                //order and ship status are both int values tied to information in the db
                $ship_method = array_search(strtoupper((string) $order->ShipmentServiceLevelCategory),
                        sql::two_column_array("SELECT id, description FROM dhs.dbo.shipping_method WHERE site IS NULL or site = 'AMAZON' "));
                $order_status = array_search(strtoupper((string) $order->OrderStatus),
                        sql::two_column_array("SELECT id, description FROM dhs.dbo.order_status WHERE site IS NULL or site = 'AMAZON' "));
                //you have to cast found elements as string or they are returned as SimpleXMLIterator objects and you can't get the value
                $arr = array(
                        'order_code'=> (string) $order->AmazonOrderId,
                        'shipping_method'=>$ship_method,
                        'amount'=> (string) $order->OrderTotal->Amount,
                        'purchased_on' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order->PurchaseDate)),
                        'market_id' => (string) $order->MarketplaceId[0],
                        'status'=> $order_status,
                        'site'=> 'AMAZON',
                        'last_update' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'employee_id'=>login::$id,
                        'addr1'=> (string) $order->ShippingAddress->AddressLine1,
                        'addr2'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->AddressLine2,
                        'city'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->City,
                        'state'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->StateOrRegion,
                        'zip'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->PostalCode,
                        'attention'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->Name,
                        'email'=>(string) $order->BuyerEmail,
                        'phone'=>$phone,
                        'first'=>array_shift($name), //remove the 0 element, use array shift so we can glue the rest of the array together for last name
                        'last'=>(implode(' ', $name)) ? implode(' ', $name): $last,
                        'fullname'=>(string) $order->BuyerName,
                        'unshipped_items'=> (string) $order->NumberOfItemsUnshipped
                );
                foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
                    $arr[$k] = strtoupper($v);

                $id = sql::merge('dhs', 'dbo', 'orders', array('order_code', 'site'), $arr, 'id');
                $arr['order_id'] = $id;
                sql::merge('dhs', 'dbo', 'order_shipping', array('order_id'), $arr);

                $orders[] = $arr;
            }
            return $orders;
        }
```

## UPDATE

Unfortunately, I am not able to install XDebugger (its a company server and I don't have permission). However, I can provide a little more insight:

- $xml->Orders will be a maximum of 100 orders (so only 100 iterations), with approximately 1000 characters per order
- Although we are doing multiple database requests per iteration (which I will remove), there are only at max 150 users hitting the server at any one time (likely fewer than 70)
- Server Environment: IIS 6, PHP 5.3, MSSQL Server 2008 R2, 48GB RAM, 16 2.7ghz processor cores (hyperthreaded to replicate 32 processors)

Comment: Please metric each line of code, how often it is executed, how long it takes average per execution and total per the line. Then please mark in the code in your question *where exactly* the 30 seconds are passed. You can do that profiling with Xdebug.

Comment: 30 seconds is a common network timeout (the other one often being 10 seconds). If you have e.g. 30.5 seconds for a bit of code, it'll probably have a network function in there that is failing (e.g. a GET or POST) and it takes 30 seconds to fail, and 0.5 seconds to process.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the database interaction. It was selecting the same data in the $shipping_method and $order_status lines on each iteration even though this is relatively static information and could be selected outside the loop. In addition, I have written another merge statement function that takes all the items in a multidimensional array and merges them at once in a single IO operation (instead of doing a single merge statement on each iteration). I will comment back after I test the efficiency of these updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was definitely related to the number of queries we were running against our database. I have created a new merge statement that accepts a multidimensional array, and removed unnecessary queries from the foreach loop, and have reduced the execution time to 24 seconds (5 iterations through the do-while loop). Below is the revised parse orders function:

```
private function parse_orders_result(SimpleXMLIterator $xml)
        {
            $shipping_methods = sql::two_column_array("SELECT id, description FROM dhs.dbo.shipping_method WHERE site IS NULL or site = 'AMAZON' ");
            $order_statuses = sql::two_column_array("SELECT id, description FROM dhs.dbo.order_status WHERE site IS NULL or site = 'AMAZON' ");
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('amz', 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01');
            $orders = array();

            foreach ($xml->Order as $order)
            {
                $last = null;
                $name = explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^A-z ]/', '', (string) $order->BuyerName)); //remove all special characters
                if (!isset($name[1]) || !$name[1])
                {
                    $attn_last = explode(' ', preg_replace('/[^A-z ]/', '',$order->ShippingAddress->Name)); //remove all special characters
                    $pos = count($attn_last) - 1;
                    $last = $attn_last[$pos];
                }
                $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', (string) $order->ShippingAddress->Phone); //remove everything that is not an int
                $phone = "(" . substr($phone, 0,3) . ")" . substr($phone,3, 3) . "-" . substr($phone, 6); //format phone number

                //order and ship status are both int values tied to information in the db
                $ship_method = array_search(strtoupper((string) $order->ShipmentServiceLevelCategory), $shipping_methods);
                $order_status = array_search(strtoupper((string) $order->OrderStatus), $order_statuses);
                //you have to cast found elements as string or they are returned as SimpleXMLIterator objects and you can't get the value
                $arr = array(
                        'order_code'=> (string) $order->AmazonOrderId,
                        'shipping_method'=>$ship_method,
                        'amount'=> (string) $order->OrderTotal->Amount,
                        'purchased_on' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order->PurchaseDate)),
                        'market_id' => (string) $order->MarketplaceId[0],
                        'status'=> $order_status,
                        'site'=> 'AMAZON',
                        'last_update' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'employee_id'=>login::$id,
                        'addr1'=> (string) $order->ShippingAddress->AddressLine1,
                        'addr2'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->AddressLine2,
                        'city'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->City,
                        'state'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->StateOrRegion,
                        'zip'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->PostalCode,
                        'attention'=>(string) $order->ShippingAddress->Name,
                        'email'=>(string) $order->BuyerEmail,
                        'phone'=>$phone,
                        'first'=>array_shift($name), //remove the 0 element, use array shift so we can glue the rest of the array together for last name
                        'last'=>(implode(' ', $name)) ? implode(' ', $name): $last,
                        'fullname'=>(string) $order->BuyerName,
                        'unshipped_items'=> (string) $order->NumberOfItemsUnshipped
                );
                foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
                    $arr[$k] = strtoupper($v);

                $orders[] = $arr;
            }
            sql::bulk_merge('dhs', 'dbo', 'orders', array('order_code', 'site'), $orders, 'id');
            sql::bulk_merge('dhs', 'dbo', 'order_shipping', array('order_code', 'site'), $orders);
            return $orders;
        }
```